# How to traverse through custom XML structure and use information in jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

As a side project I am currently trying some stuff out and getting my head around XML interpretation by the browser. What I am trying to achieve is: read and transform XML into a visible HTML structure.

Let's say that this is my XML. (For those who are curious, it is a linguistic representation of a Dutch sentence.) I want to be able to traverse through this structure, and gather information from it. (And, as an extension, transform it into my own HTML as I please.)

```
<node begin="0" cat="top" end="11" id="0" rel="top">
    <node begin="0" cat="smain" end="10" id="1" rel="--">
        <node begin="0" cat="np" end="5" id="2" rel="su">
            <node begin="0" end="1" id="3" lemma="de" pos="det" pt="lid" rel="det" root="de" word="De"/>
            <node begin="1" end="2" genus="zijd" getal="ev" graad="basis" id="4" lemma="helft" ntype="soort" pos="noun" pt="n" rel="hd" root="helft" word="helft"/>
            <node begin="2" cat="pp" end="5" id="5" rel="mod">
                <node begin="2" end="3" id="6" lemma="van" pos="prep" pt="vz" rel="hd" root="van" word="van"/>
                <node begin="3" cat="np" end="5" id="7" rel="obj1">
                    <node begin="3" end="4" id="8" lemma="al" pos="det" positie="prenom" pt="vnw" rel="det" root="alle" word="alle"/>
                    <node begin="4" end="5" getal-n="mv-n" id="9" lemma="werkloos" pos="adj" positie="nom" pt="adj" rel="hd" root="werkloos" word="werklozen"/>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
        <node begin="5" end="6" id="10" lemma="zijn" pos="verb" pt="ww" pvagr="ev" rel="hd" root="ben" word="is" wvorm="pv"/>
        <node begin="6" cat="ap" end="10" id="11" rel="predc">
            <node begin="6" buiging="zonder" end="7" graad="comp" id="12" lemma="jong" pos="adj" pt="adj" rel="hd" root="jong" word="jonger"/>
            <node begin="7" cat="cp" end="10" id="13" rel="obcomp">
                <node begin="7" conjtype="onder" end="8" id="14" lemma="dan" pos="comparative" pt="vg" rel="cmp" root="dan" word="dan"/>
                <node begin="8" cat="np" end="10" id="15" rel="body">
                    <node begin="8" end="9" id="16" lemma="30" pos="num" positie="prenom" pt="tw" rel="det" root="30" word="30"/>
                    <node begin="9" end="10" genus="onz" getal="ev" id="17" lemma="jaar" pos="noun" pt="n" rel="hd" root="jaar" word="jaar"/>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
    <node begin="10" end="11" id="18" lemma="." pos="punct" postag="LET()" pt="let" rel="--" root="." word="."/>
</node>
```

However, this didn't work as easily as expected. I tried to use jQuery's `$.parseXML(data)` and then transforming it into a jQuery object, but I don't seem to be able to travel through the internal structure of the XML that ought to be generated.

If `#xml-input` is a code-tag which contains the above XML, then the following log returns `undefined`.

```
var xml = $("#xml-input").html(),
    xmlParsed = $.parseXML(xml),
    xmlObject = $(xmlParsed);

console.log(xmlObject.node);
```

How would I transform an input into XML that I can travel to and manipulate with jQuery? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ks3p9g2f/2/) to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery methods to manipulate the XML document parsed with `$.parseXML`. For instance,

`console.log(xmlObject.find("node"));`

Returns all the `node` elements in your document

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rj3hpy6m/

For the attributes you can then use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the attributes. For example getting the attribute "cat" from the first node.

`xmlObject.find("node").first().attr("cat") // top`

Comment: And how I would I go about getting the attributes of the nodes?

Comment: Or get the first-child or something. Some basic jquery selector action.

Comment: Edited in an example of using `.attr()` which you can use to get the attributes. You can use any jQuery-methods with the collection, like getting the first-child with .children().first()

Answer (score 0):

I trust the following demo may help you figure it all out. It traverses all the nodes and outputs, `id, begin and end` values. Let us know if you have any questions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var xml = $("#xml_input").val(),
    xmlParsed = $.parseXML(xml),
    xmlObject = $(xmlParsed);
  function output( nodes ) {
    nodes.each(function() {
      $('pre.out').append( 'id='+this.id + ',\t\tbegin='+$(this).attr('begin') +  ',\tend='+ $(this).attr('end') + '\n' );
      output( $(this).children('node') );
    });
  }

  output( xmlObject.children('node') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
INPUT: <br>
<textarea id="xml_input"><node begin="0" cat="top" end="11" id="0" rel="top">
    <node begin="0" cat="smain" end="10" id="1" rel="--">
        <node begin="0" cat="np" end="5" id="2" rel="su">
            <node begin="0" end="1" id="3" lemma="de" pos="det" pt="lid" rel="det" root="de" word="De"/>
            <node begin="1" end="2" genus="zijd" getal="ev" graad="basis" id="4" lemma="helft" ntype="soort" pos="noun" pt="n" rel="hd" root="helft" word="helft"/>
            <node begin="2" cat="pp" end="5" id="5" rel="mod">
                <node begin="2" end="3" id="6" lemma="van" pos="prep" pt="vz" rel="hd" root="van" word="van"/>
                <node begin="3" cat="np" end="5" id="7" rel="obj1">
                    <node begin="3" end="4" id="8" lemma="al" pos="det" positie="prenom" pt="vnw" rel="det" root="alle" word="alle"/>
                    <node begin="4" end="5" getal-n="mv-n" id="9" lemma="werkloos" pos="adj" positie="nom" pt="adj" rel="hd" root="werkloos" word="werklozen"/>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
        <node begin="5" end="6" id="10" lemma="zijn" pos="verb" pt="ww" pvagr="ev" rel="hd" root="ben" word="is" wvorm="pv"/>
        <node begin="6" cat="ap" end="10" id="11" rel="predc">
            <node begin="6" buiging="zonder" end="7" graad="comp" id="12" lemma="jong" pos="adj" pt="adj" rel="hd" root="jong" word="jonger"/>
            <node begin="7" cat="cp" end="10" id="13" rel="obcomp">
                <node begin="7" conjtype="onder" end="8" id="14" lemma="dan" pos="comparative" pt="vg" rel="cmp" root="dan" word="dan"/>
                <node begin="8" cat="np" end="10" id="15" rel="body">
                    <node begin="8" end="9" id="16" lemma="30" pos="num" positie="prenom" pt="tw" rel="det" root="30" word="30"/>
                    <node begin="9" end="10" genus="onz" getal="ev" id="17" lemma="jaar" pos="noun" pt="n" rel="hd" root="jaar" word="jaar"/>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
    <node begin="10" end="11" id="18" lemma="." pos="punct" postag="LET()" pt="let" rel="--" root="." word="."/>
</node>
</textarea><br><br>

OUTPUT:<br>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```