# Converting XML/given input to a valid ordered list

Tags: jquery, html, xml, regex

This might be a lot to take in, but I am trying my best to explain it as clear as possible.

I have an input/upload field where a user can supply an XML file. That file looks like the following.

```
<node begin="0" cat="smain" end="10" id="1" rel="--">
    <node begin="0" cat="np" end="5" id="2" rel="su">
        <node begin="0" end="1" id="3" lemma="de" lwtype="bep" naamval="stan" npagr="rest" pos="det" postag="LID(bep,stan,rest)" pt="lid" rel="det" root="de" word="De" />
        <node begin="1" end="2" genus="zijd" getal="ev" graad="basis" id="4" lemma="helft" naamval="stan" ntype="soort" pos="noun" postag="N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan)" pt="n" rel="hd" root="helft" word="helft" />
        <node begin="2" cat="pp" end="5" id="5" rel="mod">
            <node begin="2" end="3" id="6" lemma="van" pos="prep" postag="VZ(init)" pt="vz" rel="hd" root="van" vztype="init" word="van" />
            <node begin="3" cat="np" end="5" id="7" rel="obj1">
                <node begin="3" buiging="met-e" end="4" id="8" lemma="al" naamval="stan" npagr="agr" pdtype="det" pos="det" positie="prenom" postag="VNW(onbep,det,stan,prenom,met-e,agr)" pt="vnw" rel="det" root="alle" vwtype="onbep" word="alle" />
                <node begin="4" buiging="met-e" end="5" getal-n="mv-n" graad="basis" id="9" lemma="werkloos" pos="adj" positie="nom" postag="ADJ(nom,basis,met-e,mv-n)" pt="adj" rel="hd" root="werkloos" word="werklozen" /></node>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

What I want to do now is convert that file to a list, that would mean that all `node`s become `li`s. I tried that with the following code, but the console returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`.

```
$("#xml-input").html($(this).html().replace(/node/g,"li"));
```

Also, **if** I could replace the nodes with lists that would of course not result in valid HTML. (A mere find-an-replace would result in li > li > li without any sub-lists present.)

I think this could be solved by some jQuery like the following:

```
$("li").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.parent().is("li")) {
        $this.before("<ol>");
        $this.siblings(":last").after("</ol>");
    }
});
```

The problem with this is that before running that snippet the browser has already automatically transformed the faulty HTML in a correct one. I.e. instead of something like this:

```
<li>Item 1
    <li>Item 2
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </li>
</li>
```

the browser fixes it to:

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
```

So it seems impossible to run that jQuery against the HTML that we generated.

Something else that I would like to do is replace the attributes (such as begin, buiging, end, cat et cetera) with a data-attribute. That would result in `data-begin`, `data-cat`, `data-end` and so on. I would run a `replace` on the whole block of code, but I can't: some nodes may contain actual text such as "begin" and I don't want to replace the text into `data-begin`, only the attributes. I am guessing a replace with regex should do: looking at the `<node` as a start point and `>` as an ending point. Then replace everything before `=` with the string itself preceded by `data-`. Unfortunately I lack the regex experience to make that work.

Lastly I want to add the completely overhauled HTML to another div. Something like this:

```
$("#xml-input").contents().clone().appendTo("#the-list");
```

Ideally the end result would look like this:

```
<li data-begin="0" data-cat="smain" data-end="10" data-id="1" data-rel="--">
    <ol>
        <li data-begin="0" data-cat="np" data-end="5" data-id="2" data-rel="su">
            <ol>
                <li data-begin="0" data-end="1" data-id="3" data-lemma="de" data-lwtype="bep" data-naamval="stan" data-npagr="rest" data-pos="det" data-postag="LID(bep,stan,rest)" data-pt="lid" data-rel="det" data-root="de" data-word="De" />
                <li data-begin="1" data-end="2" data-genus="zijd" data-getal="ev" data-graad="basis" data-id="4" data-lemma="helft" data-naamval="stan" data-ntype="soort" data-pos="noun" data-postag="N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan)" data-pt="n" data-rel="hd" data-root="helft" data-word="helft" />
                <li data-begin="2" data-cat="pp" data-end="5" data-id="5" data-rel="mod">
                    <ol>
                        <li data-begin="2" data-end="3" data-id="6" data-lemma="van" data-pos="prep" data-postag="VZ(init)" data-pt="vz" data-rel="hd" data-root="van" data-vztype="init" data-word="van" />
                        <li data-begin="3" data-cat="np" data-end="5" data-id="7" data-rel="obj1">
                            <ol>
                                <li data-begin="3" data-buiging="met-e" data-end="4" data-id="8" data-lemma="al" data-naamval="stan" data-npagr="agr" data-pdtype="det" data-pos="det" data-positie="prenom" data-postag="VNW(onbep,det,stan,prenom,met-e,agr)" data-pt="vnw" data-rel="det" data-root="alle" data-vwtype="onbep" data-word="alle" />
                                <li data-begin="4" data-buiging="met-e" data-end="5" data-getal-n="mv-n" data-graad="basis" data-id="9" data-lemma="werkloos" data-pos="adj" data-positie="nom" data-postag="ADJ(nom,basis,met-e,mv-n)" data-pt="adj" data-rel="hd" data-root="werkloos" data-word="werklozen" />
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

I hope that everything is clear. If not, please comment. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/87sr0dn7/) to play with.

### EDIT 1.

With @CBroe's comment in mind and [an answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26351950/1150683) I tried jQuery's parseXML() function, but I ran into trouble quite soon. I can't replace `node` by `li` and appending doesn't occur in the correct order. Here is [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/87sr0dn7/7/).

```
var xml = $("#xml-input").html(),
    xmlParsed = $.parseXML(xml),
    xmlObject = $(xmlParsed);

function output(nodes) {
    nodes.each(function () {
        output($(this).children('node'));
        $(this).replaceWith(function () {
            return $("<li />", {
                html: this.html()
            });
        }).appendTo("#the-list");
    });
}
output(xmlObject.children('node'));
```

Comment: _“the browser has already automatically transformed the faulty HTML in a correct one”_ – that should only happen if you tell it to parse the XML as HTML … so don’t. Use a proper XML parser to get a DOM, and then loop over that recursively.

Comment: @CBroe But I need it to be parsed as HTML in order to manipulate it further with jQuery, right?

Comment: There mere fact that it is not HTML and (as you already discovered yourself) gets “mangled” by the browser’s error correction when parsed as HTML should answer the question whether you “need” it to be parsed as HTML. Not only do you not “need” it parsed as HTML – but you don’t __want__ it to be parsed as HTML. I’d suggest the following as a starting point: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

Comment: See if this comes close to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/87sr0dn7/9/ First of all, I’ve gone for “real” recursion here – for each processed node, a complete OL/LI-set gets returned (so the overall result gets appended to a DIV instead of an OL in the end), and I’ve mixed a bit of “vanilla” JS in there, because that just makes it easier to get the attribute’s names and values in a loop. I added the data-attributes that get set for the LI as text content inside the LI as well, for easier checking – just remove that line if the rest of it fits your needs.

Comment: If this works for you, let me know, then I’ll add it as an answer (and maybe expand it a little).

Comment: @CBroe This looks very, very promising. Could you post it as an answer? And could you elaborate a bit on your solution? I.e. explain what is happening? I like to learn more and more, and I can by these great answers - when they are elaborately explained. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CBroe Also, what if I want to keep all the attributes (as attributes), but only have one of 'em as "text" of the list item? Say that for all items (if applicable) I want to show the value of the data-word attribute, and not all attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here’s my modified version of your function, http://jsfiddle.net/87sr0dn7/9/:

```
function output(nodes) {
    var newList = $("<ol>");
    nodes.each(function (x, e) {
        var newLI = $("<li>");
        for (var i = 0, l = e.attributes.length, a=null; i < l; i++) {
            a = e.attributes[i];
            newLI.attr("data-"+a.nodeName, a.nodeValue);
            newLI.append("data-"+a.nodeName + '=' + a.nodeValue + ' ');
        }
        newLI.append(output($(this).children('node')));
        newList.append(newLI);
    });
    return newList;
}
```

As I said, I’ve gone for “real recursion” here – you have a structure of `node` elements nested over an unknown number of levels, so recursion is the way to go.

First, a new `ol` element is created, and then all `node` elements at the current level are looped over.
In each loop iteration, a new `li` element for the node is created, and then there’s another loop over all the attributes of the node – as I said, I’ve done this in “vanilla JS”, as I could not find an easy way to loop over all attributes of a node in jQuery, and in JavaScript’s DOM implementation this is already kinda “built-in”. So for each attribute its name and value are taken, and added to the `li` as a new `data_…` attribute with the given value.

Then follows the recursive call for the child nodes of the current node, which returns an `ol`/`li` set for the nodes below it, and the result of that call gets appended to the `li`, before that itself gets appended to the `ol` we created in the beginning. And finally, that new `ol` list gets returned …

---

If you want to have only the value of one specific attribute as text content of the `li`, then simply check whether the `nodeName` of the attribute that is currently processed is the one you are looking for – if so, it gets appended to the HTML content of the `li`, otherwise not:

```
if (a.nodeName == "word") {
    newLI.append("data-" + a.nodeName + '=' + a.nodeValue + ' ');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/87sr0dn7/10/

The result of this looks a little strange, because the empty `li` elements (for the nodes that did not have a `word` attribute) have no direct text content at all now (only `li` children), so multiple `li` get displayed in one line … but formatting this to your needs is a different matter. (Also, this could be rectified by f.e. simply placing a non-breaking space in each `li` to begin with, http://jsfiddle.net/87sr0dn7/11/)

Comment: I understand that the formatting of this example may seem odd, but formatting will happen only later on. Thank you very much for this, I think I can use this for further enhancing. I use your very last fiddle (11) but I changed the append in the if-statement to `.html()` as to overwrite the non-breaking space. One more thing, what are the `x` and `e` variables? I suppose that they are inherent to the each function, but I can't find a clear answer in the docs. thanks again!

Comment: I mentioned the “strange” formatting only so that no-one is surprised by how this looks :-) And yes, `x` and `e` are the index of the element in the selection of elements that [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) operates on, and the reference to the current element itself (a “pure” JavaScript reference to the DOM element, not a jQuery object – if one is needed, use `$(e)` again). I simply used `x` here for the index (that doesn’t get used inside the function anyway), because the commonly used `i` would collide with the `for` loop counter variable of the same name otherwise.

Comment: Ow I see, thanks! Can I make one LAST wish? I want every text node to be wrapped in an `<a href="#"/>` element. So, NOT whole lists, but only the nodes themselves. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/93kefcrs/). I'm sorry for all these extra questions. Wish I could give you a reward for outstanding helpfulness! I tried  `var newLI = $("<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>");` and `newList.append('<a href="#">'+newLI+'</a>');` but neither worked, unfortunately.

Comment: The place to do this is where that text content is appended. So the `newLI.append(…)` line inside the if has to be replaced by something that creates a link first, append the text to that – and then the whole thing into the `li` … give it a try ;-)

Comment: Ah, right. Got that working! I keep bugging you, though. I only now realise that the generated list structure does not correspond to the node structure. IF you take a close look at the HTML [here](http://jsfiddle.net/87sr0dn7/11/) you will notice that `1.` the first three levels are empty, and all embedded in one another (generated correctly) `2.` the fourth, fifth and sixth node do contain words (generated correctly) but they are on the same level: not embedded in one another. This is generated wrongly. I suppose it may have to do with the self-closing tags of these nodes? `<node/>`?

Comment: Yes, I see – but that is however a problem of the browser having parsed your XML as HTML already (because you put it into the HTML), and as I said in comments right from the start, that could be problematic, and now turns out it actually is … if you log the value of the variable `xml` to console, or simply look at the DOM structure the browser has build out of your HTML/XML code, you see that it has gone wrong there already – in `xml` those self-closing `node`s miss the trailing slash before the closing `>` already, which means the are _not_ self-closing any more, […]

Comment: […] but contain the elements that should follow them as children instead already; and the DOM inspector shows the same thing, elements have become children where they should be siblings instead. So not a problem of my algorithm, but of how you “passed” the XML data to the browser in the first place ;-) In http://jsfiddle.net/87sr0dn7/12/ I fixed that, by not having the XML data in the HTML, but putting it into a JS string instead. That way, it gets handed over to the XML parser correctly. and the result is what it should be.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, using HTML entities instead of the node-tags should work fine as well? I'm going to try to make this work on textarea input, but that shouldn't be a problem I suppose because the input isn't parsed as HTML. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, if that input is coming from a textarea, it should work just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/87sr0dn7/13/ – here I’ve put it into a textarea, and I have used `&lt;`/`&gt;` instead of `<`/`>`, because that textarea content is put into the HTML already. But if it is entered by the user (manually or copy&paste), `<`/`>` can be entered normally of course.

Comment: Nope, we aren't there yet. :D Even though you can't tell from the output in the fiddle, every last node of a list also has an empty `<ol>` as a child. Of course, that's not what we want. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/87sr0dn7/14/) is the updated fiddle which is exactly what I want, except for the <ol> output in the end nodes. I solved it by [checking the HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/87sr0dn7/15/) of the <ol> but I feel there might be a neater way to do this?

Comment: OK, yeah, that was a little flaw left in my algorithm – `newLI.append(output($(this).children('node')));` was called regardless of whether the current node actually has (node) children, so a new `ol` was created in any case. With an added check for whether `$(this).children('node').length` is greater than zero (implicit check, because 0 equals false) before going down another level of the recursion, this should be fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/87sr0dn7/16/